# back up hotmail account mails to hard drive

Tags: windows-7, email, hotmail

Is there a way to back-up a my hotmail email account?

I have seen that I must install Windows Live Mail to do so, is there another way?

Comment: What email client do you use? You can configure it to connect to your Hotmail/Live account and download/check it.

Answer (score 4):

With any email POP3 client you can do that (Thunderbird, OutLook...). You have to configure it for your account, Here are the pop settings.

Incoming Server: pop3.live.com

Incoming Port: 995

SSL Encryption: yes

Outgoing Server: smtp.live.com

Outgoing port: 25 (use port 587 if the default port is not working)

Authentication: yes

TLS Or SSL: yes

[Source of Information](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/03/14/hotmail-pop3-configuration/)

Answer (score 3):

If you have Outlook, you can configure it to connect to your Hotmail account and copy all the mail.  Then you would have a local copy.  Here are some [instructions](http://www.nirmaltv.com/2009/03/27/how-to-configure-hotmail-pop3-access-in-outlook/).  Many other mail clients can perform the same task.

Answer (score 2):

The easier way is to use Windows Live Mail application which works with Microsoft hotmail/live. Here is the link to download http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=36
Also you can use outlook with live connector free from Microsoft and have all emails available offline and can back them up using both the applications.